# Agrupar por id y enseñar la mayor fecha MySQL

Tags: mysql

Tengo un problema a la hora de hacer una consulta.

Tengo una tabla con tres campos que quiero enseñar en la consulta: **ID ARTICULO, FECHA, STOCK**

En esta tabla, hay una línea en la que se guarda el **ID ARTICULO**, la **FECHA** en la que se ha modificado y el **STOCK**. Se añade una línea cada vez que se hace una venta o compra de un Artículo, y el **STOCK** se actualiza.

El problema aparece cuando intento que me enseñe el **STOCK**, de cada Artículo con la fecha mas reciente. He probado la siguiente consulta:

```
select idArticulo, max(fecha) as fecha
from stocks
group by idArticulo
order by idArticulo;
```

| idArticulo | fecha |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-09-27 |
| 2 | 2022-06-16 |

Esta consulta, me devuelve las 200 líneas de Artículos que tengo, lo cual funciona correctamente.

El problema aparece cuando intento enseñar la columna **STOCK** en esta consulta, ya que deja de agruparse y me enseña una línea por cada **STOCK** diferente que haya en cada Artículo

```
select idArticulo, max(fecha) as fecha, stock
from stocks
group by idArticulo, stock
order by idArticulo;
```

| idArticulo | fecha | stock |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-09-22 | 9 |
| 1 | 2022-09-25 | 8 |
| 1 | 2022-09-27 | 7 |
| 2 | 2022-06-16 | 3 |
| 2 | 2022-08-16 | 2 |

Esta consulta me enseña más de 500 líneas, ya que no lo está agrupando

¿Cómo podría hacer para que me enseñe el **STOCK** que hay en la línea con la última fecha?

Answer (score 0):

No puede agruparlos por 'Stock' porque tienes diferentes tipos de stock en cada línea, no un valor único como en el caso de idArticulo.
Lo único que debes de hacer es quitar 'Stock' de tu agrupación.
Así:

```
select idArticulo, max(fecha) as fecha, stock
from stocks
group by idArticulo
order by idArticulo;
```

Comment: Si lo dejo así, me salta un error diciendo: *La columna stock de la lista de selección no es válida, porque no está contenida en una función de agregado ni en la cláusula GROUP BY.*

Comment: Lo probé con los datos que proporcionas y obtuve el resultado deseado. Quizás debas compartir más información de tu tabla para ayudar mejor.

Answer (score 0):

**Solución clásica**: puedes obtenerlo con una subconsulta:

```
WITH maximas_fechas AS (SELECT id_articulo, MAX(fecha) as max_fecha)
SELECT id_articulo, max_fecha, stock as ultimo_stock
     FROM stocks 
     JOIN maximas_fechas mf 
       ON mf.id_articulo = stocks.id_articulo AND mf.max_fecha = stocks.fecha
```

**Pero ojo con la condición de borde**: si llega a producirse un empate por el hecho de guardar un timestamp con poca exactitud, tendrás duplicados.

**Solución con [WINDOW FUNCTIONS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html)** <sup>1</sup>

```
SELECT DISTINCT id_articulo, 
       MAX(fecha) OVER (PARTITION BY id_articulo ORDER BY fecha DESC) as max_fecha,
       FIRST_VALUE(stock) OVER (PARTITION BY id_articulo ORDER BY fecha DESC) as ultimo_stock
   FROM stocks
```

El DISTINCT es necesario, en este caso, porque el motor de BBDD no tiene cómo saber que no querías los duplicados idénticos.

<sup>1</sup> *Este tipo de funciones solían ser privilegio de PostgreSQL y Oracle. SQLServer ofrecía soporte parcial hasta que su versión 2012 implementó el estándar por completo. MySQL las soporta desde la versión 8 (2016) y SQLite desde la v3.25 (2018).*